# Why is SDL2 only presenting the last screen?

Tags: c++, animation, sdl-2

I would like to show a rectangle moving across the screen, but only the last screen is rendered. (I don't mind a visual trail, so previous rectangles do not have to be deleted.)

Each call to SDL_RenderPresent should add a new rectangle to the screen. Between each call to SDL_RenderPresent I waste time by using a while loop (line 134). That way, there is a little bit of time before the next rectangle is rendered. What happens is that all the while loops in each iteration of the for loop (line 113) are called and then the screen shows with the final frame. I know this because I get a print out of all the "hello" strings and then when the "hello" strings are done printing, then the final screen is shown. In the final frame all the rectangles are shown, but there wasn't any time between the rectangle renderings. They were all rendered at once.

Any help with why that is and what I can do to put some time space between each rendering of the rectangles would be great. Please see my code below.

```
 #include <chrono>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <thread>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 
 #include <SDL.h>
 #include <SDL_ttf.h>
 
 // Define MAX and MIN macros
 #define MAX(X, Y) (((X) > (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))
 #define MIN(X, Y) (((X) < (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))
 
 // Define screen dimensions
 #define SCREEN_WIDTH    600
 #define SCREEN_HEIGHT   600
 
 #define FONT_PATH   "assets/pacifico/Pacifico.ttf"
 using namespace std;
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     // Unused argc, argv
     (void) argc;
     (void) argv;
 
     // Initialize SDL2
     if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
     {
         printf("SDL2 could not be initialized!\n"
                "SDL2 Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
         return 0;
     }
 
     // Initialize SDL2_ttf
     TTF_Init();
 
 #if defined linux && SDL_VERSION_ATLEAST(2, 0, 8)
     // Disable compositor bypass
     if(!SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_X11_NET_WM_BYPASS_COMPOSITOR, "0"))
     {
         printf("SDL can not disable compositor bypass!\n");
         return 0;
     }
 #endif
 
     // Create window
     SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2_ttf sample",
                                           SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                           SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                           SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                                           SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
     if(!window)
     {
         printf("Window could not be created!\n"
                "SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
     }
     else
     {
         // Create renderer
         SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
         if(!renderer)
         {
             printf("Renderer could not be created!\n"
                    "SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
         }
         else
         {
             // Declare rect of square
             SDL_Rect squareRect;
 
             // Square dimensions: Half of the min(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
             squareRect.w = 10;
             squareRect.h = 20;
 
             // Square position: In the middle of the screen
             squareRect.x = 0;
             squareRect.y = 0;
 
             TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(FONT_PATH, 40);
             if(!font) {
                 printf("Unable to load font: '%s'!\n"
                        "SDL2_ttf Error: %s\n", FONT_PATH, TTF_GetError());
                 return 0;
             }
 
             SDL_Color textColor           = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF };
             SDL_Color textBackgroundColor = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
             SDL_Texture *text = NULL;
             SDL_Rect textRect;
 
             SDL_Surface *textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font, "Red square", textColor, textBackgroundColor);
             if(!textSurface) {
                 printf("Unable to render text surface!\n"
                        "SDL2_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
             } else {
                 // Create texture from surface pixels
                 text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, textSurface);
                 if(!text) {
                     printf("Unable to create texture from rendered text!\n"
                            "SDL2 Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                     return 0;
                 }
 
                 // Get text dimensions
                 textRect.w = textSurface->w;
                 textRect.h = textSurface->h;
 
                 SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
             }
 
             textRect.x = (SCREEN_WIDTH - textRect.w) / 2;
             textRect.y = squareRect.y - textRect.h - 10;
             for (int ii=0; ii<500; ++ii)
             {
                 // Initialize renderer color white for the background
                 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
 
                 // Clear screen
                 //SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
 
                 // Set renderer color red to draw the square
                 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
 
                 // Draw filled square
                 SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &squareRect);
 
                 // Update screen
                 SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

                 squareRect.x = ii;
                 squareRect.y = ii;
 
                 int s = ii;
                 while (s < 5000)
                 {   cout << "hello" << s <<endl;
                     ++s;
                 }
             }
 
             // Event loop exit flag
             bool quit = false;
 
             // Event loop
             while(!quit)
             {
 
 
                 SDL_Event e;
 
                 // Wait indefinitely for the next available event
                 SDL_WaitEvent(&e);
 
                 // User requests quit
                 if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                 {
                     quit = true;
                 }
             }
 
             // Destroy renderer
             SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
         }
 
         // Destroy window
         SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
     }
 
     // Quit SDL2_ttf
     TTF_Quit();
 
     // Quit SDL
     SDL_Quit();
 
     return 0;
 }
```

I added a delay and the rectangle moves correctly, but the window doesn't close immediately on clicking the x.

I replaced the else block corresponding to if(!renderer). (I also removed the textRect, since it seems to be muddying the waters.) When I click the x on the window, the rectangle still gets updated (up to 4 times) before the window closes. Before SDL_RenderPresent() is called I check the SDL_PollEvent, so the window should close before another SDL_RenderPresent() is called. What happens instead is I press the x. The rectangle keeps moving, then 4 moves later the window closes.

Is the renderer on a thread other than the main thread? Is that normal for SDL projects that the window doesn't close immediately?

Here is the updated code:

```
         if(!renderer)
         {
             printf("Renderer could not be created!\n"
                    "SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
         }
         else
         {
             // Declare rect of square
             SDL_Rect squareRect;
 
             // Square dimensions: Half of the min(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
             squareRect.w = 10;
             squareRect.h = 20;
 
             // Square position: Top left corner
             squareRect.x = 0;
             squareRect.y = 0;
 
             // Event loop exit flag
             bool running  = true;
 
             // Event loop
             while(running)
             {
                 SDL_Event e;
 
                 // Initialize renderer color white for the background
                 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
 
                 // Clear screen
                 SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
 
                 squareRect.x += 10;
                 squareRect.y += 10;
 
                 // Set renderer color red to draw the square
                 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
 
                 // Draw filled square
                 SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &squareRect);
 
                 if (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                 {
                     switch (e.type)
                     {
                         case SDL_QUIT:
                             running = false;
                             break;
                     }
                 }
 
                 SDL_Delay(500);
                 SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
             }
 
             // Destroy renderer
             SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
         }
```

Comment: Use an actual delay if you want a delay. Look at SDL examples to see how to correctly set up a render loop.

Comment: Why all the macros (`#define`)? C++ is not C - there are better options.. also see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).